# Playback of rosbag file at the same rate that messages are stored in rospy

Tags: python, rosbag, rospy, time, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to playback data that I have stored using rosbag in rospy. Is it possible to playback the rosbag file in rospy at the same rate that it is recorded? I know that I can do this from the command line, but I would like to be able to do this all in rospy if possible.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201683/playback-of-rosbag-file-at-the-same-rate-that-messages-are-stored-in-rospy/) by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2015-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The function `read_messages()` returns the time that the message was recorded (see the [rosbag Python API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rosbag/html/python/)), so you could wait for that and publish the message then. Something like this:

```
import rosbag
import time

bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
offset = bag.get_start_time() - time.time()
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages():
    # sleep until `time.time() > t + offset`
    # publish `msg` on `topic`
```

The function `get_start_time()` seems to have been added in indigo. On earlier distros, you'll need to copy it from [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/f3f1d07596cb65f1fe14a689a2d73653af55b8e2/tools/rosbag/src/rosbag/bag.py#L474).

In order for this to work properly, you'll also need to set the parameter `use_sim_time = true`, and in your rospy node you need to publish the `/clock` topic (while waiting for the time to publish the next message).

**Update:** For some of the other stuff (creating publishers for all necessary topics etc.), have a look at [rosbaglive](https://github.com/DLu/wu_ros_tools/blob/2777d2fc4c7d8e441699b172421930aaa3155743/rosbaglive/scripts/play.py).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2